# Как сделать полупрозрачный фон в Scene Builder (JavaFX) не затрагивая текст, кнопки и т.д.?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder, jtextfield, anchor

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать полупрозрачный фон в Scene Builder (JavaFX) не затрагивая текст, кнопки и т.д.?
Я добавляю AnchorPane, накидываю туда Label, ImageView, GridePane и в эту таблицу помещаю Text, TextField, Bitton, Label, comboBox и хочу, сделать например полупрозрачный фон, но что бы внутри все не становилось так же полупрозрачное, то же самое интересует как сделать полупрозрачное поле TextField, но что бы текст в нем не становился полупрозрачным? Такое вообще возможно сделать? В C# видел такое делают, то же охота такое реализовать

Comment: Похожий вопрос на основном сайте SO: [How to implement a transparent Pane with non-transparent children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717487/)

Answer (score 0):

В панели свойств SceneBuilder есть Opacity, если установить значение в 0.5, то получится 50% прозрачности